# Excel: Macro to search text for a list of keywords

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that will take a cell of text and search the cell for a list of keywords. All keywords returned need to be then inserted into a single cell.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service...

Comment: You have told us what you are trying to do, but you left out what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something that might help you. Assuming your sheet is as follows:

[image]

In `Cell D2` write the formula `=Keywords($A$2:$A$7,C2)` where `Keywords` is a ***User Defined Function***, ***$A$2:$A$7*** is you keyword range and ***C2*** is cell with text to search for keywords. Drag/Copy down formula as required.

User Defined Function `Keywords` is as follows:

```
Function Keywords(Words As Range, strText As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Words
    If InStr(1, strText, c, 1) > 0 Then Keywords = Keywords & ", " & c
        Next c
        If Keywords = 0 Then
        Keywords = "-"
    Else
        Keywords = Right(Keywords, Len(Keywords) - 2)
    End If
End Function
```